# Integration of google maps API in to cesium viewer

Tags: cesiumjs

Is there any possibility of Integrating Google maps API into cesium viewer. I mean i will send from and To locations(ex:SomeAirport to SomeHotel) to API, then it shows the complete routing and navigation as well. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in feature of Cesium, but is available as an API from 3rd parties.  For example, Bing Maps offers a [Routing API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701705.aspx).  You would still need to wire up the output of this API to display in Cesium.